# Determine if an Ad displayed and whether it was clicked

Tags: php, javascript, html, ads

I am looking for information on how to implement something similar to the Facebook and Google advertising. I would like to have a folder with different images that are Ads for businesses and display them randomly on the page.

I want to keep track of how many times the Ad displayed and also whether or not it was clicked. I am not really sure where to start so I am hoping someone can point me in the right direction or give me a starting point. I wouldn't have a problem generating the random images but I'm afraid thats going to be the easiest part of this. Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Render the image through a loader script, pass through the destination link through a forwarder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I work for a high traffic website that tracks click behavior through a process called 'tagging'. Essentialy, whenever someone clicks on something, a 'tag' is fired.

**Whats happening behind the scenes**:

a javascript event is triggered, and a 1x1 transparent pixel object is downloaded to the users browser. The URL for this image contains a query string, housing important data relevant to the clicks location.

Example, a click on a high traffic website may trigger the download or request of an image with a `src` attribute that looks something like...

`tag.gif?page=productpage&coordinate_x=3478234&coordinate_y=342345&class=ad_container_4`.

The requests for the image are then logged and persisted into a database. The overhead for a 1x1 image is very small. When these requests are captured in logs, they can be used to aggregate data for behavioral analysis.

```
requestURL = // http://url
$('.ad').click(function(){firePixel();})
firePixel = function(){
 tag = $('<img/>', {
          id: 'tag',
          border: '0',
          width: '1',
          height: '1',
          src: requestURL + '?class=' + classOfObjectClicked() + "&x_coord" + xCoordinate() _"&y_coord=" + yCoordinate()
        });
}
```

just make sure that the image is publicly accessible.

This is one of many of many ways you can track clicks ^ _ ^

Comment: `(new Image).src = tag;` is cleaner, faster, doesn't do anything to the DOM, doesn't interfere with the image ID, AND doesn't require jQuery.

Comment: +1 for (new Image) vs new Image(), didn't know you could do that

Answer (score 1):

You can send request with

```
new Image.src = "page.php?u=abc&f=12323"
```

At page.php you can get u and f with

```
$_GET['u'];$_GET['f']
```